# How to calulate a mean with known missing data

Tags: r

I've got a large data set spanning many years with many variables (Year,Site,Location, Picture Number, Taxonomy, and Count). The unique variables for Year, Site, Location are stable through out the data set, and the number of pictures taken is mostly stable (I will occasionally forget to take all the pictures in a location). But as I have set up the Taxonomy variable, if a certain Taxon is not present within a set of photos, it does not get included (no zero data) in the Location data for that Site.

But when it comes time to calculate mean densities over years, it is important to have that zero data represented in the calculations.

Here is an example what my data table looks like.

```
Year<-c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005,2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005 ,2005, 2005, 2005, 2005 ,2005 ,2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005 ,2005, 2005 ,2005, 2005, 2005 ,2005 ,2005 ,2005, 2005 ,2005 ,2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005 ,2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006 ,2006 ,2006, 2006, 2006, 2006 ,2006 ,2006 ,2006 ,2006 ,2006 ,2006 ,2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006 ,2006 ,2006, 2006 ,2006, 2006, 2006,2006, 2006, 2006 ,2006 ,2006, 2006 ,2006, 2006 ,2006 ,2006, 2006, 2006, 2006 ,2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006 ,2006,2006,2006,2006,2006)

Site<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2)

Location<-c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,3,3,3)

Photo<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,1 ,2, 3, 4, 1, 2 ,3 ,4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,1 ,2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4,1,2,3,4)

Taxonomy<-c('B' ,'B' ,'B' ,'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C','C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','C', 'C', 'C', 'C')


Count<-rnorm(119,mean=5)

DF<-data.frame(Year,Site,Location,Photo,Taxonomy,Count)
```

I've added two problems into this example data set. I'm missing a picture in my second-to-last Site/Location in 2006 (line 115). And Taxa C does not occur in the first Location of 2005, and only in the last Location of 2006.

If life were perfect and all the zero data was included in my data set I could just do

```
aggregate(Count~Year+Site+Location+Photo+Taxonomy,DF,mean)
```

or

```
aggregate(Count~Year+Site+Taxonomy,DF,mean)
```

If I wanted to look at just sites over the years.

But without the "zero" data, all my means will be off.

I've tried to write in some code that adds all the zero data, but the data set becomes monstrous and I'd rather not go that route.

Comment: Consider adding the 'correct' answer to your post, i.e., the answer you want.  I would also reduce the size of the example data set and use set.seed() if generating Count randomly.  This would help people who are trying to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Since Pandas Or R :-) excludes missing data explicitly in a  means calc, as it should, you need to do it outside the frame work by totaling the items in question and dividing it by a count taken separately of all the items...

Comment: I tried to calculate means manually (sum/n), but getting a reliable n number of photos per site was difficult. I tried something along the lines of aggregate(Photo~Year+Site+Location,FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))) to get my n for calculations- but that did not work.

Comment: you will need two calcs. one to aggregate and one to sum all items.

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(Count~Year+Site+Location+Photo+Taxonomy,DF, function(ct) mean(ct[ct != 0]) )
```

This returns mean based on the non-zero entries within each group.